# Flutter Opening they keyboard causes widget to rebuild

Tags: flutter, firebase

Whenever I click on the text field to open up the keyboard, it always rebuilds the widget, which is an issue because I have a stream builder. So whenever the stream builder rebuilds, there's some loading that happens, and I don't want that to happen. I would like for the widget not to rebuild so that the comment page looks clean.

Can you explain the reason for the rebuilding? I looked at the previous posts and people said to not use MediaQuery. I removed that, but there widget is still building!

```
class CommentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String postId;
  final PostModel post;
  final String username;
  final String photoUrl;
  final bool isAskingForComment;

  const CommentPage(
      {super.key,
      required this.postId,
      required this.post,
      required this.username,
      required this.photoUrl,
      required this.isAskingForComment});

  @override
  _CommentPageState createState() => _CommentPageState();
}

class _CommentPageState extends State<CommentPage> {
  final TextEditingController _commentController = TextEditingController();
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  final _commentFocusNode = FocusNode();

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _getCommentStream() {
    // Assuming you have a 'comments' subcollection inside a post document
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Posts')
        .doc(widget.post.id)
        .collection('Comments')
        .orderBy("createdAt")
        .snapshots();
  }

  void toggleLike(CommentModel comment) async {
    // Check if the user has already liked the comment
    bool isLiked =
        comment.likes.contains(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);

    // Update Firestore
    CollectionReference commentsCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Posts')
        .doc(widget.post.id)
        .collection('Comments');

    if (isLiked) {
      // If user has liked the comment, then unlike it
      await commentsCollection.doc(comment.id).update({
        'likes':
            FieldValue.arrayRemove([FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid])
      });
    } else {
      // If user has not liked the comment, then like it
      await commentsCollection.doc(comment.id).update({
        'likes': FieldValue.arrayUnion([FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid])
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Delay focus request until after the widget is built
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _commentFocusNode.requestFocus();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _commentFocusNode.dispose();
    scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Comments'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: _getCommentStream(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return const Center(child: Text("No comments yet."));
                  }

                  List<DocumentSnapshot> comments = snapshot.data!.docs;

                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      controller: scrollController,
                      itemCount: comments.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        CommentModel comment =
                            CommentModel.fromDoc(comments[index]);

                        if (kDebugMode) {
                          print("postedby: ${comment.likes}");
                        }

                        return Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                CachedNetworkImage(
                                  imageUrl: comment.photoUrl,
                                  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) =>
                                      CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 15.0,
                                    backgroundImage: imageProvider,
                                  ),
                                  placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                      Shimmer.fromColors(
                                    baseColor: Colors.grey[300]!,
                                    highlightColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      radius: 15.0,
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                      Icon(Icons.error),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(width: 15),
                                Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(comment.username,
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 11,
                                                fontFamily: 'CircularRegular')),
                                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                                        const Text("•",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 11,
                                                fontFamily: 'CircularRegular')),
                                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                                        Text(
                                            timeago.format(
                                                comment.createdAt.toDate()),
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 11,
                                                fontFamily: 'CircularRegular')),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(height: 2),
                                    SizedBox(
                                        // width:
                                        child: Text(comment.text,
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 12,
                                            ))),
                                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () => toggleLike(comment),
                                      child: Icon(
                                        comment.likes.contains(FirebaseAuth
                                                .instance.currentUser!.uid)
                                            ? Icons.favorite
                                            : Icons.favorite_outline,
                                        size: 15,
                                        color: comment.likes.contains(
                                                FirebaseAuth
                                                    .instance.currentUser!.uid)
                                            ? Colors.red
                                            : null, // or any default color
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    comment.likes.isNotEmpty
                                        ? GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              _showLikersModal(
                                                  context, comment.likes);
                                            },
                                            child: Column(
                                              children: [
                                                // if like is exactly 1 write like
                                                comment.likes.length == 1
                                                    ? Text(
                                                        "${comment.likes.length}",
                                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                                            fontFamily:
                                                                'CircularRegular',
                                                            color:
                                                                Colors.white),
                                                      )
                                                    : Text(
                                                        "${comment.likes.length}",
                                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                                            fontFamily:
                                                                'CircularRegular',
                                                            color:
                                                                Colors.white),
                                                      ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        : Container(),
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ));
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'CircularRegular'),
                      minLines: 1,
                      maxLines: 3,
                      focusNode:
                          widget.isAskingForComment ? _commentFocusNode : null,
                      controller: _commentController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
                        hintText: 'Add a comment...',
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.2),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          borderSide:
                              BorderSide.none, // Hides the default border
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.send),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      DateTime now = DateTime.now();
                      Timestamp currentTimestamp =
                          Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                              now.millisecondsSinceEpoch);

                      var docRef = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("Users")
                          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                          .get();

                      await FirebaseUploads.uploadComment(
                          CommentModel(
                            text: _commentController.text,
                            createdAt:
                                currentTimestamp, // Use server's timestamp
                            likes: [],
                            username: docRef.data()!['username'],
                            photoUrl: docRef.data()!['photoUrl'],
                            id: 'fdedfasfdaf',
                          ),
                          widget.post.id,
                          widget.post.url,
                          widget.post.postedBy);

                      _commentController.text = "";
                      _commentFocusNode.unfocus();
                      scrollToBottom();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: `stream: _getCommentStream(),`  Do not create the stream in the stream: parameter of the StreamBuilder.  Lift it up into State.

Answer (score 3):

Widget rebuild is expected as the screen size changes when you open the keyboard, so you should not prevent that. But instead, you should make the stream a variable in your state and initialize it inside `initState`:

```dart
class _CommentPageState extends State<CommentPage> {
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> _commentStream;
  // ...

  @override
  void initState() {
    // ...
    _commentStream = _getCommentStream();
  }
```

and then you can use it like this:

```dart
child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _commentStream,
  // ...
)
```

This way, `_getCommentStream()` won't get called again when the widget rebuilds.

This problem is addressed in Flutter's Widget of the Week video of [FutureBuilder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEdw_1B7JHY) (and that's why they had to do a second take on the video). Randal Schwartz also has a great explanation on this common mistake and how to fix it: https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Comment: @RandalSchwartz subscribed!

Comment: By the way, I'm the reason they updated the video: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/112676

Comment: @RandalSchwartz  I decided to create a canonical post where we can just reference people to there and close as duplicates..

https://stackoverflow.com/q/77760360/12349734