# Flutter FutureBuilder keeps Firing and rebuilding. It Generates a New Random Number on Every Rebuild - How can I Prevent This?

Tags: flutter, dart, future, setstate, flutter-futurebuilder

#### Context

I am encountering an issue with `FutureBuilder` in Flutter where it recreates its `Future` on every widget rebuild, causing unexpected behavior in my app.

Specifically, I have a `FutureBuilder` that fetches a random number, but each time I trigger a rebuild (e.g., by pressing a button to update a counter), it generates a new random number instead of using the initially fetched value.

#### Problem

The issue arises when I try to update a counter with a button press. Each press not only updates the counter but *also* regenerates the random number displayed by the `FutureBuilder`. I want to maintain the first generated random number unless explicitly refreshed.

Here is a video representation of the problem:

[image]

#### Code

Here is the complete runnable program that demonstrates the problem:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:math'; // For generating random numbers

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'FutureBuilder Example',
      home: FutureBuilderExample(),
    );
  }
}

class FutureBuilderExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const FutureBuilderExample({super.key});

  @override
  _FutureBuilderExampleState createState() => _FutureBuilderExampleState();
}

class _FutureBuilderExampleState extends State<FutureBuilderExample> {
  int counter = 0;

  Future<int> fetchRandomNumber() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    return Random().nextInt(100);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('FutureBuilder with Random Number')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Counter: $counter'),
          FutureBuilder<int>(
            future:
                fetchRandomNumber(), // Future is recreated here on every build
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
              } else {
                return Center(child: Text('Random Number: ${snapshot.data}'));
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            counter++; // Triggering rebuild
          });
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Question

I'm looking for a way to prevent the `FutureBuilder` from regenerating the future on each rebuild. How can I achieve this?

<sub>This question aims to serve as a canonical reference to address similar issues with `FutureBuilder` and `StreamBuilder`.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### Explanation

The issue you're experiencing with the `FutureBuilder` in Flutter is very common.

The key point to understand here is that `FutureBuilder` should be provided with a `future` that does not change on every build unless you specifically want the asynchronous operation to be re-performed.

When you create the future directly inside the `FutureBuilder`, it is re-created on every build (e.g. every `setState`), which is why you are observing the random number changing with every button press.

##### Solution: Using `initState` to Initialize the `Future`

The solution is to initialize your future *once* and use this stable reference within *FutureBuilder*. This is usually achieved by defining the future in the [`initState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html)  method of your `StatefulWidget`.

```dart
class _FutureBuilderExampleState extends State<FutureBuilderExample> {
  int counter = 0;
  late Future<int> randomNumberFuture; // Define the future here, use the `late` keyword

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    randomNumberFuture = fetchRandomNumber(); // Initialize the future in initState
  }
```

Then, in your `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
 FutureBuilder<int>(
    future: randomNumberFuture, // Use the above-initialized future here
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

##### Code example

Here's your complete refactored code snippet utilizing `initState`:

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'FutureBuilder Example',
      home: FutureBuilderExample(),
    );
  }
}

class FutureBuilderExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const FutureBuilderExample({super.key});

  @override
  _FutureBuilderExampleState createState() => _FutureBuilderExampleState();
}

class _FutureBuilderExampleState extends State<FutureBuilderExample> {
  int counter = 0;
  //1. Define the future here
  late Future<int> randomNumberFuture; // Define the future here

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //2. Initialize the future here
    randomNumberFuture =
        fetchRandomNumber(); // Initialize the future in initState
  }

  Future<int> fetchRandomNumber() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    return Random().nextInt(100);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('FutureBuilder with Random Number')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Counter: $counter', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
            FutureBuilder<int>(
              // 3. Use the initialized future here
              future: randomNumberFuture, // Use the reference
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                } else {
                  return Text('Random Number: ${snapshot.data}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24));
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            counter++; // Triggering rebuild, but not affecting the future
          });
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can now see, only the counter is updating, and *not* the random number:

[image]

##### Going further

- I recommend that you watch [this YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pp3zoNDGZUI&t=115s) video on how to create a `FutureBuilder` the correct way. Where he explains your problem at 1:55 in the video.
- [Another YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg) by Randal Schwartz on the problem and how to solve it
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56425437/12349734) StackOverflow answer.