# When reading from Flutter's StreamBuilder to Firestore, does the cache come first? Or does the server come first?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm so curious. If you read all previous documents from the server, your bill will increase due to too many reads.

If this happens, no one will be able to use Firestore.

I confirmed that if you use Future you can enable the cache using getOption.

However, no matter how much I searched in StreamBuilder, I couldn't find any cache-related options.

Let me show you some simple code.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
                  stream: db
                      .collection('user')
                      .doc(docId)
                      .collection('friendList')
                      .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true),
                  builder: (context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                          snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                      Logger().d('New message');
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        final friendDoc = snapshot.data!.docs;
                        Logger().d('access message ${friendDoc.length}');
                      }
                    }
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      Logger().d('why?');
                      return const Center(
                        child: SizedBox(
                            width: 20,
                            height: 20,
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                      );
                    }
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                    }
                    if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: Text('No data available'),
                      );
                    }
                    final friendDoc = snapshot.data!.docs;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: friendDoc.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final friendId = snapshot.data!.docs[index].id;
                        return FutureBuilder(
                          future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('user')
                              .doc(friendId)
                              .get(const GetOptions(source: Source.cache)),
                          builder: (context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<
                                      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                                  snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                ConnectionState.waiting) {
                              return const SizedBox(
                                  width: 20,
                                  height: 20,
                                  child:
                                      CircularProgressIndicator());
                            }
```

When I ran the app and checked what it was reading from Firestore, I saw that it was reading from the server. And I was devastated.

How do I make StreamBuilder read the Firestore cache first?

Of course, if there is nothing in the client cache, I want to read from the server and then from the cache.

Additionally, when new data is created, it is natural to read it from the server only the first time.

I want to read old material from the cache that I have already read.

I need help.

==========================
The Firestore documentation has this information.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen
"The initial state can come from the server directly, or from a local cache. If there is a state available in a local cache, the query snapshot will be initially populated with the cached data, then updated with the server's data when the client has caught up with the server's state."

============

However, when I refresh and check the reads in the Firestore console, it is still reading from the server.

What's wrong?

Am I doing something wrong?

Or is it better to look for another service?

Comment: This might not be the solution you're looking for, but pleas take a look at [FutureBuilder keeps firing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77760360/12349734).

it will also show you how to properly construct a future with the use of `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: dear. MendelG

It's not the answer I wanted, but thank you for your response.

My process involves getting the friend's docId into a stream and using the docId to receive information from the friend's document as a Future.
Are you okay.

I want to read the cache first.

Answer (score 0):

> When reading from Flutter's StreamBuilder to Firestore, does the cache come first? Or does the server come first?

It's not about the StreamBuilder, it's about how you read the data from Firestore. When you're calling [get()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/get.html), while online, you'll always read the data from the server, while offline, you'll always read the data from the cache. Please also note, that there is no way to force the retrieval of the data from the cache while you're connected to the Firebase servers.

On the other hand, if you are [listening for real-time updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), then you have a different behavior, while you're online, you're always reading the data from the cache first, and then the client SDK is trying to read the data from the servers to see if something has changed while the device was offline.

Bear also in mind that a StreamBuilder in Flutter is just a `Widget` that is used to listen to a stream of data and rebuild its `Widget` subtree whenever new data is emitted by the stream.

Comment: Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

I was curious about how Firebase works.
With StreamBuilder
I confirmed that the operation of getOptions(source: Source.cache) uses cache, but
The Firestore usage console still shows previously read content in the read total.
This is very scary.

Comment: Without seeing the code, I cannot be much of a help. So if you have another issue, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: So can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: sorry for the late reply.
Thank you for your valuable answer.
Currently, I am giving everything I have to focus on development.
I'm still not sure about the cache issue.
But I'm doing this: "snapshot.data!.metadata.isFromCache"
It checks true if cache, otherwise false.
This is about streams.
The get() method is used as follows: ".get(const GetOptions(Source: Source.serverAndCache))"
But the result is always "false".
I'm very disappointed, but I guess there's nothing we can do.

Comment: You're getting `false` while offline or while online?

Comment: @ Alex Mamo

It's online.
A stream always returns "true" once it has been read.
get() always returns "false".