# Why are my reads rising exponentially in Firestore using streambuilder?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a Flutter app that involves querying guest data from Firestore and updating the UI to reflect changes in guest responses to an event. I've written two main functions: fetchData to initially fetch guest data when the client logs in, and fetch to create a StreamBuilder widget that updates cards in the UI based on guest responses.

fetchData: The function is supposed to query the guests collection based on the client's EventID then get the data when the client first logs in

```dart
Future<void> fetchData() async {
  try {
    var data = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('guests');
    var identfier = {};
    print("Data is fetching...");
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('clients')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) async {
      identfier = value.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      query = data.where('EventID', isEqualTo: identfier['EventID']);
      await query.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        length = querySnapshot.size;
      });
    });
    print("Done fetching Data!");
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    print("Opps, somthing went wrong!!");
  }
}
```

then after that
fetch: This function uses StreamBuilder to listen for updates in guest responses. My intention is to update the UI (specifically, the color of guest cards) based on the reply field in each guest document

```dart
late Stream<QuerySnapshot> myStream;

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SecondPage();

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myStream = query.snapshots();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    #other things that i deleted!
          isLoading
              ? const SliverFillRemaining(
                  child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                )
              : SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: myStream,
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshots) {
                      if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshots.data?.docs.length ?? 0,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            
                            if (snapshots.hasError) {
                              return Text('Error: ${snapshots.error}');
                            }

                            final docData = snapshots.data?.docs[index].data();
                            if (docData == null || docData is! Map<String, dynamic>) {
                              return Container(); // Skip if data is not a Map
                            }

                            final Map<String, dynamic> guest = docData;
                            String guestReply = guest['reply']?.toString() ?? '';
                            String guestStatus = guest['status']?.toString() ?? '';
                            String guestName = guest['name']?.toString() ?? '';
                            String guestNumber = guest['number']?.toString() ?? '';
                            String guestMessage = guest['message']?.toString() ?? '';

                            // FILTER SECTOR
                            // ... (Filtering logic based on dropdownValue and searchQuery)
                            // ...

                            // Set card color based on status
                            Color cardColor = Colors.white;
                            if (guestStatus == 'failed') {
                              cardColor = Colors.yellow[400]!;
                            } else if (guestReply == 'Yes') {
                              cardColor = Colors.green;
                            } else if (guestReply == 'No') {
                              cardColor = Colors.red;
                            }
```

Am I doing this correctly? It's supposed to fetch only the data that changes value. So lets say 3 people said coming, then another one said coming. It should update only the last guest as coming and not fetch all 4 again!

Can someone explain why Firestore read requests are increasing so dramatically with these document updates? Is there a common mistake that could lead to such behavior, or is there a more efficient way to handle such updates to minimize read requests?

Comment: Probably cause your StreamBuilder is getting repainted every build. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/77760360/12349734 for an explanation

Comment: @MendelG I am not, i already checked and using it only once, What do you mean by repainted Also,

This is what is inside my builder ( i removed all other code)---
isLoading
              ? const SliverFillRemaining(
                  child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                )
              : SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (context, index) {
                      return fetch(index);
                    },
                    childCount: guestList.docs.length,
                  ),
                ),

Comment: `stream: query.snapshots()`.  Do not build the stream in the stream: parameter of your StreamBuilder!  See my video on this for details https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: You can use DevTools to [highlight repaints](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/inspector#highlight-repaints)