# What is the most appropriate way to initialize data in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, initialization

I'm new to Flutter and currently developing an app to learn more about this framework. The app loads data at startup, such as reading the saved session in the device's memory and verifying it through an API. It also allows changing the theme mode from light to dark and additionally checks internet connection, displaying an overlay when there is no available connection. I'm using different packages, such as flutter_secure_storage, flutter_riverpod, and internet_connection_checker_plus.

Example code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()),
  );
}

final themeProvider = StateNotifierProvider<ThemeProvider, ThemeMode>((ref) {
  return ThemeProvider();
});

class ThemeProvider extends StateNotifier<ThemeMode> {
  ThemeProvider() : super(ThemeMode.system) {
    init();
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    state = ThemeMode.dark;
  }

  toggleTheme() {
    state = state == ThemeMode.light
      ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
  }
}

final internetProvider = StateNotifierProvider<InternetProvider, bool>((ref) {
  return InternetProvider();
});

class InternetProvider extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  InternetProvider() : super(true) {
    init();
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    // Here comes a listener, this is just for code abreviation
    state = true;
  }
  
  toggleConnection() {
    state = !state;
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () => state = !state);
  }
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      themeMode: ref.watch(themeProvider),
      routes: {
        '/homepage' : (_) => const Homepage(),
      },
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: initAppData(ref),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
            return const Scaffold(
              body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),),
            );
          }
          
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString(),),),
              // Button for reload FutureBuilder?
            );
          }
          
          if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!) {
            // return login page.
          }
          
          return const Homepage();
        },
      ),
      // Builder for connection overlay
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Consumer(
          child: child,
          builder: (context, ref, child) {
            var internet = ref.watch(internetProvider);

            return Stack(
              children: [
                child!,
                !internet ? const Scaffold(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  body: Center(
                    child: Text('No internet connection',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 36,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ) : const SizedBox.shrink(),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
  
  Future<bool> initAppData(WidgetRef ref) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    return true;
  }
}

class Homepage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Homepage({super.key});
  
  @override
  Widget build(context, ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text('This is a homepage', textScaler: TextScaler.linear(1.4),),
            const SizedBox(height: 15,),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                ref.read(themeProvider.notifier).toggleTheme();
              },
              child: const Text('Toggle theme mode'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8,),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                ref.read(internetProvider.notifier).toggleConnection();
              },
              child: const Text('Toggle internet connection'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The application successfully accomplishes the described tasks, but when changing the theme mode, it re-executes the FutureBuilder and the method that loads data at startup, even showing the CircularProgressIndicator.

- How can I prevent the data from being reloaded when toggle theme mode?
- How can I force the FutureBuilder to reload in case of an error?
- Is there a better way to approach data loading at the app's startup?

Thank you.

Comment: "_it re-executes the FutureBuilder and the method that loads data at startup, even showing the CircularProgressIndicator_"  - Does this answer your question? [Flutter FutureBuilder keeps Firing and rebuilding. It Generates a New Random Number on Every Rebuild - How can I Prevent This?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77760360/flutter-futurebuilder-keeps-firing-and-rebuilding-it-generates-a-new-random-num)

Comment: @MendelG Thanks for your answer. I already knew that making MyApp Stateful could achieve this, but I omitted it because I've seen that it's not recommended for this class to be Stateful, and as I mentioned, I'm new in this. I've encountered many contradictions on the internet, and I'm not sure what is the proper way to address the three questions I have. So, if you ask me if that answers my questions, I would say I don't know, that is the best way?