# audioQuery doesn't wait for checking storage permisson

Tags: flutter, flutter-audio-query

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkPermission();
  }

  final audioQuery = OnAudioQuery();
```

```
FutureBuilder<List<SongModel>>(
        future: audioQuery.querySongs(
          sortType: null,
          orderType: OrderType.ASC_OR_SMALLER,
          uriType: UriType.EXTERNAL,
          ignoreCase: true,
        ),
```

```
Future<void> checkPermission() async {
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      bool permissionRequest = await audioQuery.permissionsRequest();

      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

i was trying to use audioQuery following tutorial on youtube, but i have error that **audioQuery.querySongs()** is excecute before user give a permission.

then i try to add permission check like this:

```
Future<void> checkPermission() async {
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      bool permissionStatus = await audioQuery.permissionsStatus();
       if (!permissionStatus) {
         await audioQuery.permissionsRequest();
       }

      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

but it doesn't work. my **DEBUGE CONSOLE** says:

```
**W/le.music_playe(29628): Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;->getDisplay()Landroid/view/Display; (light greylist, linking)
W/OnAudioQueryPlugin(29628): The application doesn't have access to the library
E/AndroidRuntime(29628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main**
```

the first warning means Showing popup to get access to storage, but after **popup show** my app crash. i think it because **audioQuery.querySongs()** excecute before user give permission.

so how to make that function wait until **checkPermission()** is done. i was trying using **Future.wait()** but i dont understand to do it. please help me to fix this Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a variable to hold the permission, and render the `FutureBuilder` conditionally

```dart
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  ...
  bool hasPermission = false;
```

and within the function, something like:

```dart
Future<void> checkPermission() async {
  if (!kIsWeb) {
    bool permissionStatus = await audioQuery.permissionsStatus();
    if (!permissionStatus) {
      permissionStatus = await audioQuery.permissionsRequest();
    }

    setState(() {
      hasPermission = permissionStatus; // --> update it here..
    });
  }
}
```

and then:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    ...
    hasPermission
      ? FutureBuilder<List<SongModel>>(
          future: audioQuery.querySongs(
          
          ),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
          },
        )
      : Center(child: Text("No permissions"))
  );
}
```

---

Btw, you shouldn't instantiate the future within the `future` parameter since it will rerun whenever your `build` method repaints. Please see:

- [Flutter FutureBuilder keeps Firing and rebuilding. It Generates a New Random Number on Every Rebuild - How can I Prevent This?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77760360/12349734)