# future builder not going to connection.done

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

so i have been using future builder in flutter .i have kept the default as CircularProgressIndicator and it always stays in that only  I am trying to make a logs app an added a logs service which deals with creating deleting modifying etc(crud)

```
class LogsView extends StatefulWidget {
  const LogsView({super.key});

  @override
  State<LogsView> createState() => _LogsViewState();
}

class _LogsViewState extends State<LogsView> {

  late final LogsService _logsService;
  String get userEmail => AuthService.firebase().currentUser!.email!;

  @override
  void initState(){
    _logsService = LogsService();
    
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    _logsService.close();
    super.dispose();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(backgroundColor: backgroundColour,
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: backgroundColour,
        title:const Text("Your logs",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)         
        ),
 
      ),  
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future:_logsService.getOrCreateUser(email: userEmail),
          
        builder: (context, snapshot) {                
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.done:
              return StreamBuilder(
                stream: _logsService.allLogs,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {                
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return const Text('Waiting for all notes...');
                    default:
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                },
              );
            default:
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

this is the logsview dart file

```
class LogsService {
  Database? _db;

  List<Databaselog> _logs = [];

  static final LogsService _shared = LogsService._sharedInstance();
  LogsService._sharedInstance();
  factory LogsService() => _shared;

  final _logsStreamController =
      StreamController<List<Databaselog>>.broadcast();

  Stream<List<Databaselog>> get allLogs => _logsStreamController.stream;

  Future<DatabaseUser> getOrCreateUser({required String email}) async {
    try {
      final user = await getUser(email: email);
      debugPrint(user.toString());
      return user;
    } on CouldnotfindUser {
      final createdUser = await createUser(email: email);
      debugPrint(createdUser.toString());
      return createdUser;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

this is logs service file code for getorcreateuser

i was trying to wait for the app to go into the connection. done but it never goes
it always is stuck in circularprogressindicator

Comment: Don't call the future function in the `FutureBuilder`, see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/77760361/13625293

Comment: NO: `future:_logsService.getOrCreateUser(email: userEmail),`. Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg