# Appearance of rebuilding in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, statefulwidget

### **The Context**

I have a flutter application and the main screen of the application is a Scaffold with a `PageView` body a `BottomNavigationBar` with four children:

```dart
// page declaration
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _children = [
    const Page1(),
    const Page2(),
    const Page3(),
    const Page4(),
  ];
}

// body
SafeArea(
  child: PageView(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    controller: _pageController, // just a PageController
    children: _children,
    onPageChanged: _onPagechanged,
  ),
)
// bottom nav bar
BottomNavigationBar(
  showSelectedLabels: false,
  showUnselectedLabels: false,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
  items: [
    icon1, icon2, icon3, icon4,
  ],
  currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
  onTap: _onItemTapped,
)

int _selectedIndex = 0; // starts at 0

void _onItemTapped(int index) {
  _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
}

void _onPagechanged(int index) {
  setState(() => _selectedIndex = index);
}
```

Each child page is constructed using a `const` constructor, is a stateful widget, and uses `with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` and this code bit:

```dart
@override
bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
```

There are some stateful widgets down the tree that use an API call to load an image from the web into a `Uint8List` state variable. That variable is initially null, and I use the `initState` override to make the call and then update the variable:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  _loadImage();
  super.initState();
}

Future _loadImage() async {
  final resourcePath = widget.item.imageUrl;
  final up = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);

  final fbss = FirebaseStorageService(up.uid);
  final image = await fbss.getResourceWithCache(resourcePath, isItem: true, saveToCache: false);
  setState(() {
    _image = image;
    _isLoaded = true;
  });
}
```

While the state variable is null (and the API call is running), I show a circular progress indicator; when the image is loaded and no longer null, I use the image in a container as a decoration image for a `BoxDecoration` widget. The color of the `BoxDecoration` widget is `Colors.grey`.

### **The Problem**

Whenever I navigate away from one screen to the next, and then go back, those widgets that are making API calls and loading images flash grey, and then the image is painted back onto the widget. Why is that? Is there a way I should be loading it to make it so that doesn't happen? I'm aware that whenever I change the screen I'm looking at the widget that holds the scaffold with the bottom nav bar rebuilds because of a state change, but why does that make the images appear to be rebuilding? I've verified that those widgets with the images *don't* in fact rebuild, but it looks like they do. I'd like to prevent this behavior. Do I need to use routes and a Navigator with my pages? What will help to prevent the appearance of reloading every time a users switches between screens?

If you need more context/code, please ask in a comment and I'll be quick to answer.

Comment: Are you following this approach? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77760360/12349734

Comment: Can you show us how you declare page1, page2, etc.?

Comment: Data that must be retained between page views should not be held within the page, but rather in something like Riverpod.

Comment: @MendelG I updated the question to show how I get the data, I believe I am following the approach you pointed out correctly

Comment: @OzanTaskiran updated to show how the pages are created

Comment: In such cases, I do 2 thing
1. Host data in parent
2. Use BLOC or Other State-Management (Which is similar to 1st but in specific business logic class)

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I have data that is being held in providers at the root level of my application, but those widgets accessing that data also appear to rebuild between page switches, despite the `build` method of the widgets not firing

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing *technically* wrong with the way that I was using the Stack widget. The problem was that the Stack widget paints renders each child widget from first to last, or from bottom to top

> The stack paints its children in order with the first child being at the bottom ([link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html#:%7E:text=The%20stack%20paints,their%20new%20location.))

Because I was using higher resolution images, each time the children in the Stack were rendered it looked like they were reloading the image, but they were just repainting to the UI and it was noticeable because of the resolution. I found that despite using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`, when I changed the tab in my app there was an inevitable state change as the `_selectedIndex` value changed. The build context of the widgets down the tree changed and therefore caused a re-render.

I fixed this by only loading 2 child items at most in the Stack instead of 5 like I had it set to previously.