# How can I optimize widget rebuilding in Flutter to prevent unnecessary database calls when selecting items?

Tags: flutter

I am currently developing a widget structure as follows:

- VoteArea: This widget holds multiple VoteItems. The options for VoteArea are implemented to be obtained from Firestore using `Question.findById(widget.questionId)`. It has a field called selectedValue to manage the currently selected option.
- VoteItem: This widget displays individual choices and is designed to invoke the `onSelected` function when tapped. The selected value is assigned to VoteArea's variable using `widget.selectedValue = value;`.

However, tapping a VoteItem triggers a complete rebuild of the entire VoteArea. During this rebuild, the app reloads data from the database, resulting in a poor user experience due to extended loading times.

Could you please provide guidance on how to avoid this issue?

```
class VoteArea extends StatefulWidget {
  String selectedValue = '';
  final String questionId;

  VoteArea({super.key, required this.questionId});

  @override
  State<VoteArea> createState() => _VoteAreaState();
}

class _VoteAreaState extends State<VoteArea> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        FutureBuilder<Question?>(
          future: Question.findById(widget.questionId),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            } else {
              Question _question = snapshot.data!;
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: List.generate(widget.staticSelections.length, (index) {
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            VoteItem(
                              text: _question.selections[index],
                              onSelected: (String value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  widget.selectedValue = value;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
          },
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            print(widget.selectedValue);
          },
          child: const Text('Vote'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't try to optimize the rebuild, but instead, you should think of a way to not have the database call on every widget rebuild. Also, please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77760361/13625293).

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a state management system using Provider, Bloc, etc. You can use `Provider.select` to build a widget that only rebuilds when the specific part of the state it depends on changes, in this case, the selected value.

Another thing you could maybe try is using caching for the data from Firebase and not allowing it to get the data more than required times.