# Chewie video display restarts every time you enter the screen

Tags: flutter

On the screen where the data is displayed, images and text manage to be displayed and loaded quickly when switching from one screen. But when switching from one screen to another, the video starts to load again, the video is always cached in the application, but the screen is always recreated and everyone downloads the video. How can this problem be solved?

It is possible that when switching to this screen, it does not reboot and use `StreamBuilder` to get data. I need your advice!

```
class _ThemeDayState extends State<ThemeDay> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<ThemeDay> {
  // Переопределите wantKeepAlive, чтобы вернуть true и сохранить состояние экрана
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>>? UpdateProfile;
  final CurrentUser _rememberCurrentUser = Get.put(CurrentUser());
  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshIndicatorKey =
  GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
  DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat('dd.MM.yy HH:mm');

  final CurrentUserUpdate currentUserUpdate = CurrentUserUpdate();

  Future<List<Post>> fetchPost() async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(API.UploadPostVideoAndImages),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final posts = (json.decode(response.body) as List)
          .map((json) => Post.fromJson(json))
          .toList();

      if (posts.isNotEmpty) {
        // Save the first post ID to SharedPreferences
        await RememberUserPrefs.savePostIdToSharedPreferences(posts[0].id);
        // print(posts[0].id);
      } else {
        // Handle the case when there are no posts
        // print('No posts available');
        // You can choose to throw an exception or handle it in a different way
      }

      return posts;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load products');
    }

  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    fetchPost();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context); // Это важно, чтобы сохранить состояние экрана
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Center(
          child: Image.asset("assets/images/forgot_logo.png", height: 100,),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff2a2a2a),
        elevation: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Container(),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
            child: Image.asset("assets/images/telegram_logo.png",
                width: 25, height: 25),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            colors: [
              Color(0xff2a2a2a),
              Color(0xff0a090e),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: Future.wait([fetchPost(), currentUserUpdate.getUserData()]),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              List<Post> posts = snapshot.data![0];
              return GestureDetector(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  cacheExtent: 10000,
                  itemCount: posts.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    Post post = posts[index];
                    ProfileModel user = snapshot.data![1];
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => Comment(post: post),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Row(
                          children: [
                            ClipOval(
                              child: (user.image.isNotEmpty && post.image != null && post.image.isNotEmpty)
                                  ? CachedNetworkImage(
                                imageUrl: '${API.UploadImageProfile}${user.image}',
                                key: Key(user.image),
                                height: 50,
                                width: 50,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(), // Показываем индикатор загрузки
                                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset('assets/images/default_avatar.png'), // Показываем изображение по умолчанию в случае ошибки загрузки
                              )
                                  : Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/default_avatar.png',
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                              ),
                            ),

                            Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                        0.03),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                  CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    post.name != "" && post.family != ""
                                        ? Text(
                                      "${post.name} ${post.family}",
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Color(0xffC194F1),
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                        : const Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Text("User ",style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                        ),),
                                        Text("User",style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                        ),),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Text(dateFormat.format(DateTime.parse(post.timestamp)),
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                            fontSize: 12)),
                                  ],
                                )),
                          ],
                        ),
                        subtitle:  Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 12, bottom: 12),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage("assets/images/tape_background_cart.png"),
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 12, bottom: 12),
                              child: Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    if (post.images.isNotEmpty)
                                      ClipRRect(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                          key: UniqueKey(),
                                          imageUrl: post.images.isNotEmpty ? '${API.hostConnectImagesPath}${post.images[0]}' : '',
                                          height: 100,
                                          width: 100,
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          placeholder: (context, url) => Container(),
                                          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    if (post.videos.isNotEmpty)
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 100,
                                        height: 100,
                                        child: CachedVideoPlayer(
                                          videoUrl: '${API.hostConnectImagesPath}${post.videos.isNotEmpty ? post.videos[0] : ""}',
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 10, right: 5),
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                Text(
                                                  post.theme,
                                                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.amber, fontSize: 13),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(height: 2), // Добавляем пространство между theme и description
                                            Row(
                                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                Flexible(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    post.description,
                                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      fontSize: 12,
                                                    ),
                                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                    maxLines: 4,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
                  child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      height: 1,
                      child: LinearProgressIndicator(color: Colors.grey, backgroundColor: Colors.black,)),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CachedVideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoUrl;

  CachedVideoPlayer({required this.videoUrl});

  @override
  _CachedVideoPlayerState createState() => _CachedVideoPlayerState();
}

class _CachedVideoPlayerState extends State<CachedVideoPlayer> {
  late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  late ChewieController _chewieController;
  bool _isVideoLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.videoUrl);
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio: 12 / 16, // соотношение сторон видео
      autoPlay: false, // автоматическое воспроизведение
      looping: false, // зацикливание видео
      allowFullScreen: true,
      showControls: false,
    );

    // Обработчик ошибки загрузки видео
    _videoPlayerController.addListener(() {
      if (_videoPlayerController.value.hasError) {
        print('Ошибка загрузки видео: ${_videoPlayerController.value.errorDescription}');
        // Обработка ошибки загрузки (по вашему усмотрению)
      }
    });

    // Обработчик ошибки воспроизведения видео
    _chewieController.videoPlayerController.addListener(() {
      if (_chewieController.videoPlayerController.value.hasError) {
        print('Ошибка воспроизведения видео: ${_chewieController.videoPlayerController.value.errorDescription}');
        // Обработка ошибки воспроизведения (по вашему усмотрению)
      }
    });

    _videoPlayerController.initialize().then((_) {
      setState(() {
        _isVideoLoading = false; // Устанавливаем флаг, когда видео загружено
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Stack(
      children: [
        Chewie(controller: _chewieController),
        if (_isVideoLoading)
          Center(
            child: Container(
                width: 15,
                height: 15,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to do this when I get to the screen where the video is displayed, it loaded faster or did not reboot at all.

Comment: About the FutureBuilder, you should see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77760360/13625293)