# I'm trying to get the name from the database but I can't get it

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
final String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
  child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid).snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Text(snapshot.data?["name"]);
      } else {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    },
  ),
),
```

I want to display the name data saved in Firebase on the screen, but even though I type it according to the documentation, CircularProgressIndicator keeps returning. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't build the stream inside the `StreamBuilder`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77760360/13625293) (It's about FutureBuilder but applies to StreamBuilder as well)

Comment: You're not handling errors. Before the `if (snapshot.hasData) {` place `if (snapshot.hasError) return Text(`ERROR: ${snapshot.error}`);`

Comment: I solved it. The problem wasn't in the code. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: As indicated by @FrankvanPuffelen, the problem is indeed in the code. You are subscribing to a stream in a `build` which shall never be done since it will re-subscribe for every build of the widget, potentially causing memory leaks.