# Why is my function not invoking in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

this is the code to get message text from firestore using streambuilder and list view .I dont know why _buildlistitem is not working.I also tried printing numbers to check it on but no use.can somebody help

```
Widget _buildMessagesList() {
    print(1);
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream:
          _chatService.getMessages(widget.receiveruid, _auth.currentUser!.uid),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Error ${snapshot.error}');
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Text('Loading');
        }
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return Text('No data available');
        } else {
          return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data!.docs
                .map((doc) => _buildMessageItem(doc))
                .toList(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

Widget _buildMessageItem(DocumentSnapshot document) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    print(3);
    var alignment = (data['senderId'] == _auth.currentUser!.uid)
        ? Alignment.centerRight
        : Alignment.centerLeft;

    return Container(
      alignment: alignment,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(data['senderEmail']),
          Text(data['message']),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I want invoke the function _buildMessageItem in the code.

Comment: Don't build the stream inside StreamBuilder, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77760360/13625293) (it's about FutureBuilder, but applies to StreamBuilder as well).

Comment: give please code for getMessages from chat service or all code of chat service - to more correctly answer

Comment: thanks Bro that was helpful but might as well can u help me with the function invoking

Comment: https://github.com/VishnuKumar-cyber/Result_App-Flutter my respository the chat folder is where the file is

Comment: I'm watching now

Comment: I'm added answer, below

Comment: Ur a Life Saver bro worked perfectly .I will update screenshot in the github profile .Do watch if u have free time. @OKJI

Answer (score 0):

At class `ChatService`

in method `Stream<QuerySnapshot> getMessages(String userId, String otherUserId)`

change **'timestamp'** to **'time'**

error
`.orderBy('timestamp', descending: false)`

fixed
`.orderBy('time', descending: false)`

```dart
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getMessages(String userId, String otherUserId) {
    List<String> ids = [userId, otherUserId];
    ids.sort();
    String chatRoomId = ids.join("_");
    print(2);
    return _store
        .collection('chat_rooms')
        .doc(chatRoomId)
        .collection('messages')
        .orderBy('time', descending: false)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

in your model `Message` in method `Map<String, dynamic> toMap()` you use **`'time': timestamp,`**

```dart
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'senderId': senderid,
      'senderEmail': senderemail,
      'receiverId': receiverid,
      'message': message,
      'time': timestamp,
    };
  }
```