# Why does the Futurebuilder widget show an old snapshot?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I have a Flutter Web project. I have two pages mainly: one where I list sports, and another where I modify a particular sport. To navigate I use the `context.router.navigateNamed` method of the `auto_route` package.

When I first navigate to my edit page, everything works correctly, but if I navigate to the edit page a second time (by navigating to the list page and pressing another sport to edit), the page is reused because it was already in the stack (as expected), but the `Futurebuilder` does not work correctly (it does not show the loading, show the old `snapshot.data`, and directly jumps to showing the new `snapshot.data`).

[image: Described steps]

This is my code:

```
class EditSportView extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;

  const EditSportView({Key? key, @PathParam('id') required this.id})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditSportViewState createState() => _EditSportViewState();
}

class _EditSportViewState extends State<EditSportView> {
  late SportProvider sportProvider;
  late MenuProvider menuProvider;

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _keyForm = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  late TextEditingController _nameController;

  final List<GameModeEntity> selectedGameModes = [];

  Timer? _timer;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    sportProvider = Provider.of<SportProvider>(context, listen: false);
    menuProvider = Provider.of<MenuProvider>(context, listen: false);
    _nameController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _nameController.dispose();
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 8.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        child: CustomCard(
          boxShadowBlurRadius: 0.0,
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
            child: FutureBuilder<List>(        // <-------- The problem seems to be here
              future: Future.wait([
                sportProvider.getSport(GetSportRequest(widget.id)),
                sportProvider.getAllGameModes(),
              ]),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData &&
                    !snapshot.data!.any((element) => element == null)) {
                  SportEntity sport = snapshot.data![0];
                  _nameController.text = sport.name;

                  List<GameModeEntity> gameModes = snapshot.data![1];

                  return Form(
                    key: _keyForm,
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        const CustomTextTitle(
                            width: double.infinity, text: "Sport Settings"),
                        const CustomDivider(),
                        _nameTextFormField(),
                        _gameModeSelectionFormField(
                            gameModes,
                            gameModes
                                .map((e) => sport.gameModes!
                                    .any((element) => element.id == e.id))
                                .toList()),
                        _createEventButton(context),
                        _cancelEventButton(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _nameTextFormField() {
    return CustomTextFormField(
      showCounter: true,
      controller: _nameController,
      isRequired: true,
      showPrefixIcon: false,
      showSuffixIcon: false,
      autofocus: true,
      topLabel: AppGlobals.nameText,
      textColor: Colors.black,
      validator: (String? value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return AppGlobals.fieldRequiredText;
        }
        if (!AppGlobals.onlyLettersNoSpaceRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          return AppGlobals.invalidNameText;
        }
        return null;
      },
      onChanged: (String value) {},
    );
  }

  Widget _gameModeSelectionFormField(
      List<GameModeEntity> gms, List<bool> initialSelection) {
    return CustomGenericFormField<GameModeEntity>(
      topLabel: "Game Modes",
      items: gms.map((gm) => MultiSelectItem(gm, gm.label)).toList(),
      initialValue: gms
          .asMap()
          .entries
          .where((e) => initialSelection[e.key])
          .map((e) => e.value)
          .toList(),
      validator: (values) {
        if (values?.isEmpty ?? true) {
          return "Select at lease one";
        }
        return null;
      },
      onTap: (values) {
        selectedGameModes.clear();
        for (var element in values.where((e) => e != null)) {
          selectedGameModes.add(element!);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Container _createEventButton(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 180,
        child: CustomOutlinedButton(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
          text: "Update Sport",
          borderColor: AppGlobals.selectedSeparatorColor,
          isFilled: true,
          backgroundColor: AppGlobals.primaryColor,
          borderRadius: 5.0,
          textSize: 14,
          onPressed: () async {
            if (_keyForm.currentState!.validate()) {
              context.loaderOverlay.show();
              UpdateSportRequest request = UpdateSportRequest(
                  id: widget.id,
                  name: _nameController.text,
                  gameModes: selectedGameModes.map((e) => e.id).toList());

              sportProvider.updateSport(request).then((value) {
                context.loaderOverlay.hide();
                if (value ?? false) {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    barrierDismissible: false,
                    builder: (buildContext) {
                      _timer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                        Navigator.of(buildContext).pop();
                        menuProvider
                            .setCurrentPageUrl(RouteGlobals.listSportsRoute);
                        context.router
                            .navigateNamed(RouteGlobals.listSportsRoute);
                      });
                      return const ConfirmationDialog(
                          msg: AppGlobals.sportUpdateSuccessfullyText);
                    },
                  );
                }
              });
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container _cancelEventButton() {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 180,
        child: CustomOutlinedButton(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
          text: AppGlobals.cancelText,
          borderColor: AppGlobals.selectedSeparatorColor,
          isFilled: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
          borderRadius: 5.0,
          textSize: 14,
          onPressed: () {
            menuProvider.setCurrentPageUrl(RouteGlobals.listSportsRoute);
            context.router.navigateNamed(RouteGlobals.listSportsRoute);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why this happens? Thank you.

**UPDATE**
Following the comments I changed my code as follows:

```
(...)
@override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    sportProvider = Provider.of<SportProvider>(context, listen: false);
    menuProvider = Provider.of<MenuProvider>(context, listen: false);
    _nameController = TextEditingController();

    future = Future.wait([
      sportProvider.getSport(GetSportRequest(widget.id)),
      sportProvider.getAllGameModes(),
    ]);
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant EditSportView oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    if (oldWidget.id != widget.id) {
      future = Future.wait([
        sportProvider.getSport(GetSportRequest(widget.id)),
        sportProvider.getAllGameModes(),
      ]);
    }
  }
(...)

FutureBuilder<List>(
              future: future,
              builder: (...)
```

But unfortunately I continue to have the same problems. When the widget is updated for the second time, it is as if the `Futurebuilder` does not update until the `Future` call finishes again, even when the `build` method has been invoked.

Comment: Don't build the future inside the `FutureBuilder`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77760360/13625293).

Comment: It does not work. Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide future (variable) instead of future function.

Try this

```
class _EditSportViewState extends State<EditSportView> {
  ....
  late Future<List> fetchData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData = Future.wait([
                sportProvider.getSport(GetSportRequest(widget.id)),
                sportProvider.getAllGameModes(),
              ]); 
  }
.......

FutureBuilder<int>(
    future: fetchData, 
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
.......
```

Detailed explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/77760361/3552066

Comment: It does not work. Please check my updated question.