Lot of rebuilds with CustomScrollView and SliverGrid
I have a sliver grid inside custom scroll view. When I scroll the tiles get rebuild and result in a suboptimal experience (see demo below).
Roughly my code is as follows:
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    // Some slivers.
    SliverGrid.builder(
      itemCount: n,
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        crossAxisSpacing: 8,
        mainAxisSpacing: 8,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        Image(
         PhotoProvider(photoId[index]),
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      }
    ),
  ],
)

where PhotoProvider is a custom image provider that fetches the image from Firebase Storage.
I tried adding a cacheExtent to the CustomScrollView but that resulted in a choppy scrolling.
When I checked the network tab in Chrome, requests are generated as I am scrolling but the browser fetches the images from the cache.


"that fetches the image from Firebase Storage." - You are probably using a  FutureBuilder incorrectly. Please see this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/77760360/12349734

I have looked into it, the FutureBuilder doesn't seem to be the problem. The parent widget doesn't get reloaded. It's the sliver grid that gets rebuild often and slow.

When I changed from displaying images to a static red box then it works much better. I guess I have to optimize my images.

I have the same problem and so far I have found only one solution. I added AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to my photo widget. But I'm not sure that this will be the right and optimal solution for large lists.

UPD. My solution is not correct. I catch the crash my app with memory overflow.
